# Implement splitting payment in ERC-20 token

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, contract-design, polygon

I am new to this topic. I'm trying to implement a method to split the payment inside the token contract itself. I know that there is a separate contract for payment splitting, but I want to try to implement it inside token contract.

I've written such a method. Could you please tell me:

1. Is it safe to make the payment this way?
2. Is it possible to implement in any other way (but inside token contract itself)?

```
    function splitPayment(address from, address firstReceiver, address secondReceiver, uint256 amount) public {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(firstReceiver != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(secondReceiver != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");

        unchecked {
            _balances[from] = fromBalance - amount;
        }

        _balances[firstReceiver] += amount * 70 / 100;
        _balances[secondReceiver] += amount * 30 / 100;

        emit SplittedTransfer(from, firstReceiver, secondReceiver, amount);
    }
```

Comment: You may need a fixed-point math library if you want to accurately calculate percentages. I recommend using [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: Also: consider using [custom errors](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/) instead of revert reason strings. Compared to revert reason strings, custom errors are easier to work with, more gas efficient, and more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. It will be better if you split payment in this way, Here You dont have to worry a lot

```
function splitTransfer(address firstReceiver ,address secondReceiver,  uint256 amount) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _transfer(owner, firstReceiver, amount* 70 / 100);
        _transfer(owner, secondReceiver, amount* 30 / 100);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This way of splitting tokens seems ok, but you need to make sure that the tokens cannot be transferred by anyone. You have two options here:

1. Tokens can only be split by their owner
2. Tokens can only be split by their owner or by someone that has been given allowance

Option 1 would look like this:

```
require(from == msg.sender, "ERC20: transfer of foreign assets");
```

Option 2 would look like this:

```
require(from == msg.sender || _allowances[from][msg.sender] >= amount, "ERC20: exceeds allowance");
```

If you go with option 2, you also have to make sure to update `_allowances` and emit the `Approval` event.

I think it would be better to emit 2 `Transfer` events instead of creating a new event, as the `Transfer` event is standardised.

Comment: Thank you for useful information)